# Как кратко записать параметры meta_query wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Параметры выборки можно записать в виде строки, вот пример:

```
$args = "&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_key=price&order=DESC";
```

Как в таком кратком виде записать следующий запрос:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'custom_products',
'meta_key' => 'special_price',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'catalog',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $reqterm
    )
));
```

Не ясно как объединить параметры tax_query, там ведь массив в массиве.
Начало вроде понятно, но как дальше?

```
$args = "&post_type=custom_products&meta_key=special_price&orderby=meta_value_num&order=ASC&tax_query=???";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так:

```
$args = "&post_type=custom_products&meta_key=special_price&orderby=meta_value_num".
"&order=ASC".
"&tax_query[taxonomy]=catalog".
"&tax_query[field]=slug".
"&tax_query[terms]={$reqterm}";
```

Переносы строк вставил для удобства чтения.

Можно для генерации такой строки воспользоваться функцией [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php).